# artifacts when visualizing mesh with librviz

Tags: ros, rviz, mesh, collada, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a project in which we are trying to visualize large meshes with textures in a custom written app that uses librviz. When loading collada files that were downloaded from 3D Warehouse, we notice a few bad things that happen when visualizing them.

Specifically, we experienced two problems when visualizing [this mesh](http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=3c3c1d53d7849db328e546aa74f65fca&prevstart=0):

1. Some textures weren't loaded at all - After we downloaded it, we had to fix the .dae file so that librviz wouldn't crash because the image paths were wrong. First, we had to go change the file paths of the textures so that they were correct. Then we had change the filenames so they were case sensitive. At this point, we didn't get any errors or warnings from rviz (even with the rviz logger set to DEBUG).

- ex. Check out the cars in the images below.

2. White "artifacts" when visualizing the mesh from **some** perspectives. If I were to move the camera around, the white lines would disappear in some areas and show up in other areas. It's difficult to find a perspective that makes them disappear.

- ex. Check out the white lines in the images below.

I've seen the very impressive gazebo worlds that the folks at OSRF made for the DRC, so I would bet it's either a problem in rviz that doesn't exist in gazebo OR I'm doing something wrong.

Any advice on how to make the meshes visualize properly from ALL perspectives and to make all of the textures load would be much appreciated.

(Please note that I really don't know much about 3D graphics in general.....so I use the term "artifacts" here because I hear people using it to describe a whole bunch of crap that happens when working with meshes. Please tell me if there is a real term that describes what we're seeing...)

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66362/artifacts-when-visualizing-mesh-with-librviz/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like a type of z fighting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).  I'm wondering if the model you downloaded includes multiple coincident meshes for level of detail or special effects.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1